# How to upgrade Ruby patch level for 1.9.3 in RVM?

Tags: ruby, rvm, ruby-upgrade

Based on a previous StackOverflow question it looked like the correct way to upgrade Ruby to the latest patch level was this:

```
$ rvm upgrade 1.9.2 1.9.2-p0
Are you sure you wish to upgrade from ruby-1.9.2-p0 to ruby-1.9.2-p136? (Y/n): Y
```

However, this doesn't seem to work for me:

```
$ rvm upgrade 1.9.3 1.9.3-p0
Are you sure you wish to upgrade from ruby-1.9.3-p194 to ruby-1.9.3-p0? (Y/n): n
Cancelling upgrade.
$ rvm upgrade 1.9.3-p0 1.9.3
Are you sure you wish to upgrade from ruby-1.9.3-p194 to ruby-1.9.3-p194? (Y/n): n
Cancelling upgrade.
$ rvm upgrade 1.9.3-p0 1.9.3-p194
Are you sure you wish to upgrade from ruby-1.9.3-p194 to ruby-1.9.3-p194? (Y/n): n
Cancelling upgrade.
$ rvm upgrade 1.9.3-p194 1.9.3-p0
Are you sure you wish to upgrade from ruby-1.9.3-p194 to ruby-1.9.3-p0? (Y/n): n
Cancelling upgrade.
```

Is there a more appropriate way to upgrade Ruby versions with RVM?

Comment: What version(s) do you actually have installed?

Comment: What patch level do you currently have installed? p194 is the latest.

Comment: Why would you want to go *back* 194 patch levels?

Comment: I currently have 1.9.3-p0.  I want to upgrade it to the latest which seems to be 1.9.3-p194.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I already had ruby 1.9.3-p194 installed, so I had both that and 1.9.3-p0.  That's why the upgrade command was confusing.  It won't upgrade 1.9.3-p0 if a newer version is already there...

Answer (score 13):

First update RVM:

```
rvm get stable
```

Next upgrade ruby:

```
rvm upgrade 1.9.2
```

RVM will automatically detect existing version of 1.9.2 and will check if it is lower then highest available patchlevel:

1. if update is possible it will continue
2. if update is not possible it will report error

Comment: if I try `rvm upgrade 1.9.3`, I get `Usage:

    rvm upgrade [source ruby] [destination ruby]`

Comment: this means your 1.9.3 is already upgraded, have you updated rvm first ?